# jQuery simplyScroll scroll content align to right

Tags: jquery, simplyscroll

i have a scroll content and i'm using the jQuery simplyScroll.

How i can align the content to right when page is loaded? i want to display first the contents from the right side.

my example: http://www.eleftherohori.gr/testsyn.php

this is my javascript code outside of the .js file.

```
(function($) {
$(function() { //on DOM ready
    $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
        auto: false,
        speed: 10
    });
});
```

})(jQuery);

it's possible to scroll left and right on mouse click and not on mouse over?

thank you.

Comment: show ur code in fiddle or something and btw questions based on plugins won't be answered here ..

Comment: AFAIK there is no configuration related to what you are asking.

Comment: you can view the source code on the example page. is a .js file. i can't wright the entire code on this page.